# How to compute fast the containment order of all intersections of a collection of sets

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a follow-up to [How to get all intersections of sets in python fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622153):

I have a finite collection A = {A1,...Ak} of finite sets Ai of integers and I want to compute in `Python` the following:

1. All intersections of subsets of A: F = { intersection of B : B is a subset of A }. This was the above question with a decently fast solution.
2. a. All pairs (X,Y) for X,Y being sets in F such that X is subset of Y.

   b. All pairs (X,Y) for X,Y being sets in F such that X is subset of Y and there is no set Z in F such that X subset of Z subset of Y. In other words, so that no set Z fits in between X and Y in containment order. Such a pair (X,Y) is called *cover*.

> Why do I want to do that? -- I want to compute face lattices of 10^7 polytopes. In the scenario in mind, the collection A above contains 600 sets. It is indeed the [famous 600-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600-cell), the computation currently takes about 6 secs, and I would like that to go down by a factor of 10, if possible.

The 6 secs to get 2.a. is simply done by doing

```
# this is John Coleman's function from above question's answer
def allIntersections(frozenSets):
    universalSet = frozenset.union(*frozenSets)
    intersections = set([universalSet])
    for s in frozenSets:
        moreIntersections = set(s & t for t in intersections)
        intersections.update(moreIntersections)
    return intersections

def all_intersections(lists):
    sets = allIntersections([frozenset(s) for s in lists])
    return [list(s) for s in sets]


A = [[19, 40, 41, 48], [19, 44, 45, 49], [23, 42, 43, 50], [23, 46, 47, 51], [19, 40, 41, 52], [19, 44, 45, 53], [23, 42, 43, 54], [23, 46, 47, 55], [2, 25, 36, 56], [0, 24, 32, 56], [24, 25, 56, 57], [24, 32, 56, 57], [16, 32, 56, 57], [1, 24, 32, 57], [25, 36, 56, 57], [16, 36, 56, 57], [3, 25, 36, 57], [8, 28, 34, 58], [10, 29, 38, 58], [28, 29, 58, 59], [28, 34, 58, 59], [20, 34, 58, 59], [29, 38, 58, 59], [20, 38, 58, 59], [9, 28, 34, 59], [11, 29, 38, 59], [6, 27, 37, 60], [4, 26, 33, 60], [5, 26, 33, 61], [26, 27, 60, 61], [26, 33, 60, 61], [16, 33, 60, 61], [27, 37, 60, 61], [7, 27, 37, 61], [16, 37, 60, 61], [12, 30, 35, 62], [14, 31, 39, 62], [30, 35, 62, 63], [20, 39, 62, 63], [20, 35, 62, 63], [30, 31, 62, 63], [31, 39, 62, 63], [15, 31, 39, 63], [13, 30, 35, 63], [0, 24, 32, 64], [1, 24, 32, 64], [8, 28, 34, 65], [9, 28, 34, 65], [3, 25, 36, 66], [2, 25, 36, 66], [11, 29, 38, 67], [10, 29, 38, 67], [4, 26, 33, 68], [5, 26, 33, 68], [12, 30, 35, 69], [13, 30, 35, 69], [6, 27, 37, 70], [7, 27, 37, 70], [15, 31, 39, 71], [14, 31, 39, 71], [4, 33, 68, 72], [0, 32, 64, 72], [18, 64, 72, 73], [32, 64, 72, 73], [32, 33, 72, 73], [1, 32, 64, 73], [18, 68, 72, 73], [5, 33, 68, 73], [33, 68, 72, 73], [2, 36, 66, 74], [6, 37, 70, 74], [3, 36, 66, 75], [7, 37, 70, 75], [36, 66, 74, 75], [37, 70, 74, 75], [36, 37, 74, 75], [22, 66, 74, 75], [22, 70, 74, 75], [12, 35, 69, 76], [8, 34, 65, 76], [18, 65, 76, 77], [34, 65, 76, 77], [34, 35, 76, 77], [18, 69, 76, 77], [35, 69, 76, 77], [13, 35, 69, 77], [9, 34, 65, 77], [10, 38, 67, 78], [14, 39, 71, 78], [38, 67, 78, 79], [22, 71, 78, 79], [22, 67, 78, 79], [38, 39, 78, 79], [39, 71, 78, 79], [15, 39, 71, 79], [11, 38, 67, 79], [0, 40, 48, 80], [19, 40, 48, 80], [19, 48, 49, 80], [8, 44, 49, 80], [19, 44, 49, 80], [2, 40, 52, 81], [10, 44, 53, 81], [19, 52, 53, 81], [19, 40, 52, 81], [19, 44, 53, 81], [19, 40, 80, 81], [19, 44, 80, 81], [23, 42, 50, 82], [23, 50, 51, 82], [1, 42, 50, 82], [23, 46, 51, 82], [9, 46, 51, 82], [23, 54, 55, 83], [3, 42, 54, 83], [23, 42, 54, 83], [23, 42, 82, 83], [11, 46, 55, 83], [23, 46, 55, 83], [23, 46, 82, 83], [19, 45, 49, 84], [12, 45, 49, 84], [4, 41, 48, 84], [19, 41, 48, 84], [19, 48, 49, 84], [19, 45, 84, 85], [19, 41, 84, 85], [6, 41, 52, 85], [19, 41, 52, 85], [14, 45, 53, 85], [19, 45, 53, 85], [19, 52, 53, 85], [23, 43, 50, 86], [5, 43, 50, 86], [23, 50, 51, 86], [23, 47, 51, 86], [13, 47, 51, 86], [7, 43, 54, 87], [23, 43, 54, 87], [23, 43, 86, 87], [23, 54, 55, 87], [23, 47, 86, 87], [15, 47, 55, 87], [23, 47, 55, 87], [8, 28, 65, 88], [0, 24, 64, 88], [9, 28, 65, 89], [28, 65, 88, 89], [17, 28, 88, 89], [17, 24, 88, 89], [1, 24, 64, 89], [24, 64, 88, 89], [64, 65, 88, 89], [4, 26, 68, 90], [12, 30, 69, 90], [5, 26, 68, 91], [13, 30, 69, 91], [26, 68, 90, 91], [21, 26, 90, 91], [68, 69, 90, 91], [30, 69, 90, 91], [21, 30, 90, 91], [10, 29, 67, 92], [2, 25, 66, 92], [29, 67, 92, 93], [66, 67, 92, 93], [11, 29, 67, 93], [17, 29, 92, 93], [25, 66, 92, 93], [17, 25, 92, 93], [3, 25, 66, 93], [14, 31, 71, 94], [6, 27, 70, 94], [21, 31, 94, 95], [21, 27, 94, 95], [15, 31, 71, 95], [31, 71, 94, 95], [70, 71, 94, 95], [27, 70, 94, 95], [7, 27, 70, 95], [2, 25, 56, 96], [0, 80, 88, 96], [0, 40, 56, 96], [2, 40, 81, 96], [2, 40, 56, 96], [0, 40, 80, 96], [40, 80, 81, 96], [2, 81, 92, 96], [17, 25, 92, 96], [2, 25, 92, 96], [0, 24, 88, 96], [0, 24, 56, 96], [24, 25, 56, 96], [17, 24, 88, 96], [17, 24, 25, 96], [28, 29, 58, 97], [80, 88, 96, 97], [80, 81, 96, 97], [44, 80, 81, 97], [8, 28, 88, 97], [8, 28, 58, 97], [8, 44, 58, 97], [8, 80, 88, 97], [8, 44, 80, 97], [81, 92, 96, 97], [17, 29, 92, 97], [17, 92, 96, 97], [17, 28, 29, 97], [17, 28, 88, 97], [17, 88, 96, 97], [10, 29, 92, 97], [10, 29, 58, 97], [10, 44, 58, 97], [10, 44, 81, 97], [10, 81, 92, 97], [6, 41, 85, 98], [6, 41, 60, 98], [4, 41, 60, 98], [6, 85, 94, 98], [4, 41, 84, 98], [4, 84, 90, 98], [41, 84, 85, 98], [6, 27, 94, 98], [6, 27, 60, 98], [26, 27, 60, 98], [4, 26, 90, 98], [4, 26, 60, 98], [21, 27, 94, 98], [21, 26, 90, 98], [21, 26, 27, 98], [14, 45, 85, 99], [21, 30, 31, 99], [14, 31, 62, 99], [30, 31, 62, 99], [14, 45, 62, 99], [21, 90, 98, 99], [21, 30, 90, 99], [84, 90, 98, 99], [45, 84, 85, 99], [84, 85, 98, 99], [12, 30, 62, 99], [12, 45, 62, 99], [12, 45, 84, 99], [12, 30, 90, 99], [12, 84, 90, 99], [85, 94, 98, 99], [21, 94, 98, 99], [14, 85, 94, 99], [14, 31, 94, 99], [21, 31, 94, 99], [3, 83, 93, 100], [1, 42, 82, 100], [3, 42, 57, 100], [1, 42, 57, 100], [42, 82, 83, 100], [3, 42, 83, 100], [1, 82, 89, 100], [1, 24, 89, 100], [17, 24, 89, 100], [1, 24, 57, 100], [17, 25, 93, 100], [3, 25, 57, 100], [3, 25, 93, 100], [17, 24, 25, 100], [24, 25, 57, 100], [17, 93, 100, 101], [82, 83, 100, 101], [11, 83, 93, 101], [83, 93, 100, 101], [11, 29, 59, 101], [11, 29, 93, 101], [17, 29, 93, 101], [9, 82, 89, 101], [82, 89, 100, 101], [17, 89, 100, 101], [11, 46, 83, 101], [11, 46, 59, 101], [9, 46, 59, 101], [9, 46, 82, 101], [46, 82, 83, 101], [9, 28, 59, 101], [17, 28, 29, 101], [28, 29, 59, 101], [17, 28, 89, 101], [9, 28, 89, 101], [5, 43, 86, 102], [5, 86, 91, 102], [7, 43, 61, 102], [5, 43, 61, 102], [21, 27, 95, 102], [7, 27, 95, 102], [7, 27, 61, 102], [5, 26, 61, 102], [26, 27, 61, 102], [21, 26, 27, 102], [21, 26, 91, 102], [5, 26, 91, 102], [43, 86, 87, 102], [7, 43, 87, 102], [7, 87, 95, 102], [86, 91, 102, 103], [86, 87, 102, 103], [15, 31, 63, 103], [30, 31, 63, 103], [15, 31, 95, 103], [87, 95, 102, 103], [15, 87, 95, 103], [15, 47, 63, 103], [15, 47, 87, 103], [47, 86, 87, 103], [13, 30, 63, 103], [13, 30, 91, 103], [13, 86, 91, 103], [13, 47, 63, 103], [13, 47, 86, 103], [21, 91, 102, 103], [21, 30, 91, 103], [21, 30, 31, 103], [21, 95, 102, 103], [21, 31, 95, 103], [0, 48, 72, 104], [4, 33, 72, 104], [4, 33, 60, 104], [4, 41, 60, 104], [4, 48, 72, 104], [4, 41, 48, 104], [32, 33, 72, 104], [0, 32, 72, 104], [0, 32, 56, 104], [0, 40, 56, 104], [40, 41, 48, 104], [0, 40, 48, 104], [16, 32, 56, 104], [16, 32, 33, 104], [16, 33, 60, 104], [40, 41, 104, 105], [40, 41, 52, 105], [41, 60, 104, 105], [16, 60, 104, 105], [40, 56, 104, 105], [16, 56, 104, 105], [2, 40, 56, 105], [2, 40, 52, 105], [2, 36, 56, 105], [16, 36, 56, 105], [16, 37, 60, 105], [16, 36, 37, 105], [2, 52, 74, 105], [36, 37, 74, 105], [2, 36, 74, 105], [6, 52, 74, 105], [6, 41, 52, 105], [6, 41, 60, 105], [6, 37, 60, 105], [6, 37, 74, 105], [12, 35, 76, 106], [12, 45, 62, 106], [12, 35, 62, 106], [8, 44, 49, 106], [8, 49, 76, 106], [12, 49, 76, 106], [44, 45, 49, 106], [12, 45, 49, 106], [20, 35, 62, 106], [8, 44, 58, 106], [20, 34, 58, 106], [8, 34, 58, 106], [20, 34, 35, 106], [8, 34, 76, 106], [34, 35, 76, 106], [20, 62, 106, 107], [20, 38, 39, 107], [20, 39, 62, 107], [10, 38, 78, 107], [38, 39, 78, 107], [10, 53, 78, 107], [20, 58, 106, 107], [20, 38, 58, 107], [10, 38, 58, 107], [44, 58, 106, 107], [10, 44, 58, 107], [10, 44, 53, 107], [14, 39, 62, 107], [14, 39, 78, 107], [14, 53, 78, 107], [14, 45, 53, 107], [44, 45, 106, 107], [44, 45, 53, 107], [14, 45, 62, 107], [45, 62, 106, 107], [16, 32, 57, 108], [1, 32, 57, 108], [16, 32, 33, 108], [16, 33, 61, 108], [5, 33, 61, 108], [1, 32, 73, 108], [32, 33, 73, 108], [1, 50, 73, 108], [5, 33, 73, 108], [5, 50, 73, 108], [1, 42, 50, 108], [1, 42, 57, 108], [5, 43, 61, 108], [5, 43, 50, 108], [42, 43, 50, 108], [7, 37, 61, 109], [3, 36, 57, 109], [3, 42, 57, 109], [7, 43, 61, 109], [42, 43, 108, 109], [43, 61, 108, 109], [42, 57, 108, 109], [16, 36, 57, 109], [16, 36, 37, 109], [16, 57, 108, 109], [16, 61, 108, 109], [16, 37, 61, 109], [36, 37, 75, 109], [7, 37, 75, 109], [3, 36, 75, 109], [3, 42, 54, 109], [42, 43, 54, 109], [7, 43, 54, 109], [3, 54, 75, 109], [7, 54, 75, 109], [34, 35, 77, 110], [13, 35, 63, 110], [13, 35, 77, 110], [13, 47, 63, 110], [9, 34, 77, 110], [9, 51, 77, 110], [13, 51, 77, 110], [9, 46, 51, 110], [13, 47, 51, 110], [46, 47, 51, 110], [20, 35, 63, 110], [20, 34, 35, 110], [9, 34, 59, 110], [20, 34, 59, 110], [9, 46, 59, 110], [11, 38, 59, 111], [11, 38, 79, 111], [15, 47, 63, 111], [11, 55, 79, 111], [15, 47, 55, 111], [15, 55, 79, 111], [11, 46, 59, 111], [46, 47, 55, 111], [11, 46, 55, 111], [38, 39, 79, 111], [15, 39, 79, 111], [15, 39, 63, 111], [20, 38, 39, 111], [20, 39, 63, 111], [20, 38, 59, 111], [47, 63, 110, 111], [20, 59, 110, 111], [20, 63, 110, 111], [46, 59, 110, 111], [46, 47, 110, 111], [8, 65, 88, 112], [18, 65, 76, 112], [8, 65, 76, 112], [8, 49, 76, 112], [0, 64, 88, 112], [64, 65, 88, 112], [18, 64, 65, 112], [18, 64, 72, 112], [0, 64, 72, 112], [0, 48, 72, 112], [8, 49, 80, 112], [8, 80, 88, 112], [48, 49, 80, 112], [0, 48, 80, 112], [0, 80, 88, 112], [4, 68, 90, 113], [4, 84, 90, 113], [12, 84, 90, 113], [18, 68, 69, 113], [68, 69, 90, 113], [12, 69, 90, 113], [4, 68, 72, 113], [18, 68, 72, 113], [18, 69, 76, 113], [12, 69, 76, 113], [4, 48, 84, 113], [4, 48, 72, 113], [12, 49, 76, 113], [48, 49, 84, 113], [12, 49, 84, 113], [18, 76, 112, 113], [49, 76, 112, 113], [18, 72, 112, 113], [48, 49, 112, 113], [48, 72, 112, 113], [2, 66, 92, 114], [66, 67, 92, 114], [52, 53, 81, 114], [2, 52, 81, 114], [2, 81, 92, 114], [22, 66, 67, 114], [22, 67, 78, 114], [2, 66, 74, 114], [2, 52, 74, 114], [22, 66, 74, 114], [10, 53, 81, 114], [10, 53, 78, 114], [10, 67, 78, 114], [10, 81, 92, 114], [10, 67, 92, 114], [6, 85, 94, 115], [6, 52, 85, 115], [52, 53, 85, 115], [14, 85, 94, 115], [14, 53, 85, 115], [52, 53, 114, 115], [6, 52, 74, 115], [52, 74, 114, 115], [14, 71, 94, 115], [70, 71, 94, 115], [6, 70, 94, 115], [6, 70, 74, 115], [22, 74, 114, 115], [22, 70, 74, 115], [22, 70, 71, 115], [14, 71, 78, 115], [53, 78, 114, 115], [14, 53, 78, 115], [22, 78, 114, 115], [22, 71, 78, 115], [18, 64, 65, 116], [18, 65, 77, 116], [50, 51, 82, 116], [1, 50, 82, 116], [9, 51, 82, 116], [9, 51, 77, 116], [9, 65, 77, 116], [18, 64, 73, 116], [1, 64, 73, 116], [1, 50, 73, 116], [64, 65, 89, 116], [1, 64, 89, 116], [9, 65, 89, 116], [1, 82, 89, 116], [9, 82, 89, 116], [18, 73, 116, 117], [18, 77, 116, 117], [51, 77, 116, 117], [18, 69, 77, 117], [13, 51, 86, 117], [13, 51, 77, 117], [13, 69, 77, 117], [18, 68, 69, 117], [18, 68, 73, 117], [13, 69, 91, 117], [13, 86, 91, 117], [68, 69, 91, 117], [5, 86, 91, 117], [5, 68, 73, 117], [5, 68, 91, 117], [50, 51, 116, 117], [5, 50, 86, 117], [50, 51, 86, 117], [5, 50, 73, 117], [50, 73, 116, 117], [11, 55, 83, 118], [3, 66, 75, 118], [3, 54, 75, 118], [3, 54, 83, 118], [54, 55, 83, 118], [11, 55, 79, 118], [11, 67, 79, 118], [66, 67, 93, 118], [3, 83, 93, 118], [3, 66, 93, 118], [11, 67, 93, 118], [11, 83, 93, 118], [22, 66, 67, 118], [22, 67, 79, 118], [22, 66, 75, 118], [54, 55, 87, 119], [54, 55, 118, 119], [55, 79, 118, 119], [54, 75, 118, 119], [22, 75, 118, 119], [22, 79, 118, 119], [22, 71, 79, 119], [22, 70, 71, 119], [70, 71, 95, 119], [22, 70, 75, 119], [7, 54, 75, 119], [7, 54, 87, 119], [7, 70, 75, 119], [7, 87, 95, 119], [7, 70, 95, 119], [15, 71, 79, 119], [15, 55, 79, 119], [15, 55, 87, 119], [15, 71, 95, 119], [15, 87, 95, 119]]
from itertools import combinations
F = all_intersections(A) # all intersections: function from other question
                         # takes 415 ms
F = sorted(F,lambda x,y: cmp(len(x),len(y)))
pairs = [ (x,y) for x,y in combinations(F,2) if set(y).issuperset(x) ]
                         # takes ~6 sec
```

An example is the square with vertices labelled with {1,2,3,4}: the set A is then {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,1}}, the intersections F are {{},{1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},[4,1},{1,2,3,4}}, and the pairs in question are

```
({},{1}),({},{2}),({},{3}),({},{4}),
({1},{1,2}),({1},{4,1}),
({2},{1,2}),({2},{2,3}),
({3},{2,3}),({3},{3,4}),
({4},{3,4}),({4},{4,1}),
({1,2},{1,2,3,4}),({2,3},{1,2,3,4}),({3,4},{1,2,3,4}),({4,1},{1,2,3,4})
```

Once you are given the set `F`, I don't think there is anything better than just comparing the elements. But I am more thinking of an algorithm that computes (1) and (2) at the same time using the knowledge about stuff that was just intersected.

Following the solution by David K below, given the **why**, there are two more assumptions that can be used:

1. The resulting order is graded with a unique minimal and a unique maximal element. This is, every maximal chain F0 < F1 < ... < Fm of cover relations has the same length and F0 is the empty set and Fm is the union of the input sets A. We call the set Fi to be of rank i, which is well-defined given the graded-ness.
2. Every rank M set is the intersection of exactly 2 rank M+1 sets.

Many thanks!

Comment: How long does "all_intersections(A)" take on the input? I am assuming that `all_intersections` it is a NP problem in that the worst case is exponential relative to size of input no?

Comment: The potential output size is exponential in the input size... it takes 415 ms to compute the 2642 intersections (starting with 600 sets). So generally speaking, the expected output is not too big compared to the input, because most intersections are empty or small, and small intersections are obtained in many different ways.

Comment: can you post the code used for all_interseections in the question?

Comment: I copied it from the other post.

Comment: just wondering how much time do you save by replacing `F = sorted(F,lambda x,y: cmp(len(x),len(y)))` with `F.sort(key=len)`

Comment: `3.5 ms` vs `691 µs`, so that's certainly cleaner but not in the interesting order of magnitude.

Comment: you are also converting from sets to lists and then to sets. Can `all_intersections` return sets or must they be lists?

Comment: That takes `5ms` each, so also not interesting to optimize.

Comment: Would it be OK to just be able to output the containment order of the sets of vertices in sub-polytopes of a polytope, given the description of an n-dimensional polytope as a collection of sets of vertices of (n-1)-dimensional polytopes (i.e. the "why do I want to do that" part), rather than solving the much more general (and more computationally difficult) problem described in the first few paragraphs of the question (accepting arbitrary sets of integers as input)?

Comment: @David K:No, it wouldn't. The object in question is called the *combinatorial type* of a polytope, and we want to abstract away from concrete polytopes towards studying these combinatorial types without referencing back any concrete realization.

Comment: Also, I doubt that one can do better than studying sets of integers by using concrete realizations in space with vertices given by algebraic numbers (ie solution to algebraic equations).

Comment: I'm not talking about changing the way you express the input and output. You'd still be operating on sets of integers. But the sets of integers you can abstract from a polytope in this way are not completely general sets of integers. It's not clear to me why you must have an algorithm that solves the problem for input that you will never use. (Alternatively, perhaps you _are_ really interested in the more general problem, and the description of the input as a "polytope" is misleading. That also is unclear.)

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood your suggestion. What kind of restrictions do you think the input might have which can be used to make an improved algorithm, even for polytopes? The generality we look at is as follows: This containment order on intersections of subsets of `A` is supposed to yield an [Eulerian poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_poset). And that's exactly the generality we want to work in ...

Comment: ... These Eulerian posets are *atomic* and *coatomic*, meaning that they are all obtained via the procedure described above (but there are indeed restrictions given implicitly which I do not see to be used in an algorithm): the only additional property that we can take into account is that every interval in that poset contains the same number of odd and even degree elements, but that doesn't seem to provide any immediate improvement of the algorithm.

Comment: Idea #1: Sort the members of F first by *size* and then lexicographically.  The size ordering means you then only need to test whether X_i is a subset of X_j for i < j, which is roughly half as many tests; the lex ordering within each block of constant size means that adjacent sets have equal prefixes, so by precomputing a table lcp[i] that tells you the longest common prefix of sets X_i and X_{i-1}, each subset test that fails can potentially rule out a contiguous block of subsequent superset candidates.

Comment: Idea #2 (only effective if for each set X there is usually a proper superset Y of X such that |Y|=|X|+1): To find the "smallest superset" Y for some given set X (while answering 2a), you can take X and try inserting each possible other integer into it, and seeing if this one-larger set exists (e.g. by maintaining a hashtable (maybe called a dictionary in Python?) containing all sets in F): if so, it must be the smallest superset.  (If not, you'll need to try adding each possible *pair* of other integers, etc., or fall back on your current approach.)

Comment: Idea #3: Rewrite this tiny piece of code in C++ or some other compiled language.  If all you're looking for is a small constant-factor improvement, this is usually the way to go.

Comment: "if for each set X there is usually a proper superset Y of X such that |Y|=|X|+1" is not satisfied in most cases. If it where, I think it would already imply that it is a *simplicial set* saying that all subsets of the elements of `A` are in `F` and the cover relation is as you say.

Comment: Idea #3: that's probably what I will do anyway (I actually plan to use cython).

Comment: My point is that the problem statement (prior to "why do I want to do that") says only that A is a finite collection of finite sets of integers, so an algorithm to solve that problem has to work for _any_ finite collection of finite sets of integers. Not all such collections (I believe) result in Eulerian posets. If you place the restriction that you only accept input for which the answer would be an Eulerian poset, then you can take advantage of properties of Eulerian posets to do less calculation. For example, you only have to check containment for sets that are one grade apart.

Comment: @David K: "you only have to check containment for sets that are one grade apart" that is correct, but telling what "being only one grade apart" means can only be done *after* computing the poset. It is certainly not "differ by one in size".

Comment: All the input sets will be of the same grade (one less than their union), is that not correct? And for any lower grade N, each set of grade N can be found by intersecting two sets of grade N+1 (though it may occur several times as intersections of different pairs of sets, which the algorithm must account for). Or is that not always true for a general polytope?

Comment: "All the input sets will be of the same grade (one less than their union)" only applies to the [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) in the given dimension. The property that every grade N set is the intersection of two grade N+1 sets is a property of *simplicial polytopes*.  Think of a pyramid over a square: Then `A = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,5},{2,3,5},{3,4,5},{4,1,5}}` as there is the square bottom plus four triangles, which is the smallest example of a non-simplicial polytope.

Comment: For the N-simplex, all input sets will be of the same _cardinality,_ one less than their union, and indeed that is not true for a general polytope. But I was writing about _grade,_ not cardinality. For the set A representing the square pyramid, you gave a collection of three sets of grade 3 (if the empty set has grade 0). The bigger problem with what I said before is that while you get every grade-N set by intersecting every pair of grade-(N+1) sets, you also (in general) get other sets of lower grades, and figuring out which are which may not be trivial.

Comment: Okay, I thought you mean *cardinality* when writing *grade*. I think we are now on the same page, at least in the sense that we both see the point that one does not know which grade one gets when intersecting two grade N sets. So I wouldn't see how to use that property in an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that takes advantage of the assumption that the lists in the input are the facets of an abstract polytope. Instead of taking all intersections of collections of facets, 
this function assumes the input is a complete list of M-faces (polytopes of rank M) within a polytope of rank M + 1.
It then performs a loop in which each iteration takes a complete list of M-faces and produces a complete list of (M-1)-faces, while accumulating all the containment pairs for those two lists of faces.

The main loop of the function intersects each pair of M-faces and builds a structure listing each intersection and the M-faces that contained it.
These intersections include all the (M-1)-faces, but also include
some lower-rank faces. The lower-rank faces can be identified
by observing that each of them is a subset of an (M-1)-face,
so any intersection which is a subset of another intersection is eliminated.

A rough breakdown of the running time is 40% to intersect pairs of faces,
40% to keep track of which M-faces contained each of the resulting
intersections, 10% to eliminate faces of rank less than M - 1,
and 10% to write the containment pairs to the output list.
My computer seems to be slower than yours 
(about 8 seconds instead of 6 or 6.5 seconds for the original function),
but the end result of the new function is a list of all the containment
pairs between each rank and the next rank, about 10x-15x faster than the
original function that produces all containment pairs (including
the ones that "skip" ranks).

Note that not every list of lists of integers is valid input for the new
function, because there are collections of sets of points that are not
facets of an abstract polytope. I did not include code to check the input
for correctness.

To check correctness of the output, I added some (rather slow) code to the original function to find all pairs (s,t) in the (original) output list
such that pairs of the form (s,u) and (u,t) were also in the list,
and then return a revised list with all those pairs removed.
I also modified both the new and old functions by invoking `sorted()` on
each list of integers they put in the output so that the output lists
would compare correctly.
I then confirmed that both functions produced identical output.

By the way, I doubt this function is a pythonic as it could have been.
Comments suggesting improvements in that matter are welcome.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

def generatePairs(A):
    # It is assumed that A consists exactly of all the facets of an abstract
    # polytope of rank N; that is, the abstract polytope is a graded poset
    # in which the minimal element is the empty set and has rank -1, the
    # maximal element is the polytope's body, which has rank N, and A
    # contains all facets of the polytope, which have rank N - 1.
    # Then within the graded poset,
    # each element of rank 0 is a point and has cardinality 1;
    # each element of rank 1 is an edge and has cardiality 2;
    # each element of rank M (where M > 1) is a rank-M polytope and has
    # cardinality at least M + 1, but may have greater cardinality.

    # We start with the facets (rank N-1).
    rank_to_intersect = [frozenset(s) for s in A]

    # Construct the body (rank N).
    polytope_body = list(frozenset.union(*rank_to_intersect))
    body_size = len(polytope_body)

    # covering_pairs will be all the pairs of polytopes (s,t) such that
    # rank(s) + 1 == rank(t) and s is a subset of t. Initially we populate
    # it with just the pairs whose ranks are respectively N-1 and N.
    covering_pairs = [(s, polytope_body) for s in A]

    while (len(rank_to_intersect) > 0) and (len(rank_to_intersect[0]) > 2):
        # For some integer M such that M > 1, rank_to_intersect contains all
        # the polytopes of rank M. At the end of each iteration of the loop,
        # rank_to_intersect will contain all the polytopes of rank M - 1.
        # Also, all the pairs (x,y) where rank(x) = M - 1 and rank(y) = M
        # will have been added to covering_pairs.

        container_map = defaultdict(list)
        while rank_to_intersect:
            s = rank_to_intersect.pop()
            for t in rank_to_intersect:
                x = s & t
                if len(x) > 1:
                    container_map[x].extend([s, t])
                    # Note that the list container_map[x]
                    # may contain duplicates

        # The keys of container_map, consisting of all pairwise
        # intersections of polytopes of rank M, include all polytopes
        # of rank M - 1 but also some polytopes of lower ranks.
        # Any polytope of a lower rank, however, is a subset of
        # a polytope of rank M - 1 that is also in the list.

        min_size   = min([len(s) for s in container_map.keys()])
        max_size   = max([len(s) for s in container_map.keys()])
        size_range = range(min_size, max_size + 1)
        candidates = dict([(i, []) for i in size_range])
        for s in container_map.keys():
            candidates[len(s)].append(s)

        # Repopulate rank_to_intersect with the polytopes of rank M - 1.
        for set_size in size_range:
            larger_sizes = range(set_size + 1, max_size + 1)
            for s in candidates[set_size]:
                if not any(any(t >= s for t in candidates[i])
                           for i in larger_sizes):
                    # We now know that s has rank M - 1, not a lower rank.
                    rank_to_intersect.append(s)

        # Add all the (rank-(M - 1), rank-M) pairs to covering_pairs.
        for s in rank_to_intersect:
            # container_map[s] may contain duplicates; avoid them.
            containers = frozenset(container_map[s])
            covering_pairs.extend([(list(s), list(t)) for t in containers])

    # At the end of the loop, rank_to_intersect contains the rank-1
    # polytopes, that is, the edges.
    # Each edge contains each of its two endpoints.
    points_with_duplicates = []
    for e in rank_to_intersect:
        covering_pairs.extend([([p], list(e)) for p in e])
        points_with_duplicates.extend(e)

    # List the containment pairs of the empty set without duplicating points.
    points = frozenset(points_with_duplicates)
    covering_pairs.extend([([], [p]) for p in points])

    return covering_pairs
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for working it out! It does produce the correct output (checked on the 600-cell against another algorithm I implemented today). The algorithm I implemented uses the Graph class from sagemath.org (so is not really appropriate here) and is about 2.5 times slower than yours. I will go through your code tomorrow and post comments in case I have any.

Comment: One comment on the assumption you make: you only assume that the output is a ranked lattice and that every rank M face is the intersection of two rank M+1 faces. That does apply to a much wider class of structures that only polytopes. E.g., (not that you necessarily care but) the class of face lattices of compatible oriented matroids also satisfies this assumption, as does the class of face lattices of triangulated spheres that are not polytopal.

Comment: The big improvement that you used *and which I oversaw* is that you only need to intersect all pairs of rank N+1 faces (which you actually already wrote yesterday, but I didn't realize that to be the big advantage) to obtain all rank N faces.

Comment: The tricky part was to distinguish the faces of the desired rank from the intersections of lower rank. I was not entirely sure what the impact that step would have on running time until I tried it (and it makes a great deal of difference in running time depending on _how_ that step is done). Also, thanks for the commentary on the class of problems to which the algorithm might apply--it never hurts to know a sharper bound on the applicability of an algorithm.

Comment: I posted another rather different algorithm in case you want to have a look -- feedback and improvements welcome!

Answer (score 0):

could you just let me know the running time for the following changes?

```
def all_intersections(lists):
    sets = allIntersections([frozenset(s) for s in lists])
    return list(sets)


A = ...
F = all_intersections(A) 
F.sort(key=len)
pairs = [(x,y) for x,y in combinations(F,2) if y.issuperset(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks for playing with it! The `y.issuperset(x)` gives a factor of 2 compared to `set(y).issuperset(x)` (so ~3sec), so that's indeed worth doing. But I was more hoping for a clever way of constructing the set `F` that provides these `pairs` along the way so that I can do the complete computation in < 1sec total.

Comment: I know, sorry, Im super busy and don't really have the time to think too hard about it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative algorithm which only uses the graded-ness assumption above. The idea is that

1. every intersection except the union of `A` has a cover which is computable rather quickly
2. this produces a spanning tree of the order starting at the top element give by union of `A`
3. one then computes the ranks successively and compare elements only for ranks that differ by 1

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict

   # this is John Coleman's function from
   # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622153
   # compute all intersections including the empty intersection
   # corresponding to the union of all sets in `A`.
   def all_intersections(A):
       # using frozensets for intersections
       A = map(frozenset,A)
       A.sort(key=len)

       # the union of A as the ground set
       universalSet = frozenset.union(*A)

       # computing the intersections successively
       intersections = set([universalSet])
       for s in A:
           moreIntersections = set(s & t for t in intersections)
           intersections.update(moreIntersections)
       return intersections

   def ranked_pieces(intersections):
       # this is to shortcut the length tests below
       lens = { s:len(s) for s in intersections }
       V = sorted(intersections, lambda x,y:cmp(lens[x],lens[y]))

       m = len(V)

       lower_covs = defaultdict(set)
       # we first compute the spanning tree...
       for i,x in enumerate(V):
           for j in range(i+1,m):
               y = V[j]
               if lens[x] < lens[y] and y.issuperset(x):
                   lower_covs[y].add(x)
                   # since V is sorted according to the size,
                   # we have surely found a cover and stop
                   break

       # ... and then the level sets
       level = set([V[-1]])
       level_sets = [level]

       while level:
           level = set.union(*[lower_covs[v] for v in level])
           level_sets.append(level)

       # the level sets are ordered backwards now
       # i.e., level_sets[0] is the biggest set
       # and level_sets[-1] is the empty set
       return level_sets

   def ranked_pieces_to_covers(ranked_pieces):
       # this is because we want tuples and not sets
       # and we want to compute them only once
       back_ref = { f:tuple(sorted(f)) for i in range(len(ranked_pieces)) for f in ranked_pieces[i] }
       covs = []
       for i in range(len(ranked_pieces)-1):
           high = ranked_pieces[i]
           low  = ranked_pieces[i+1]

           for x in low:
               for y in high:
                   if y.issuperset(x):
                       covs.append((back_ref[x], back_ref[y]))
       return covs

   def generate_covers(A):
       return ranked_pieces_to_covers(ranked_pieces(all_intersections(A)))
   ```

For the test data of the 600-cell, the algorithm by David K is much quicker:

```
    sage: %time X = generatePairs(A)
    CPU times: user 363 ms, sys: 28.2 ms, total: 392 ms
    Wall time: 373 ms
    sage: %time Y = generate_covers(A)
    CPU times: user 1.09 s, sys: 25.3 ms, total: 1.12 s
    Wall time: 1.08 s
    sage: set(X) == set(Y)
    True
```

but the "denser" the sets are, the better the other algorithm becomes:

The simplex on 10 vertices:

```
    sage: m = 10; A = [ [i for i in range(m) if i != j] for j in range(m) ]
    sage: %time X = generatePairs(A)
    CPU times: user 151 ms, sys: 4.33 ms, total: 156 ms
    Wall time: 144 ms
    sage: %time Y = generate_covers(A)
    CPU times: user 118 ms, sys: 17.3 ms, total: 136 ms
    Wall time: 106 ms
    sage: set(X) == set(Y)
    True
```

and the simplex on 14 vertices:

```
    sage: m = 14; A = [ [i for i in range(m) if i != j] for j in range(m) ]
    sage: %time X = generatePairs(A)
    CPU times: user 56.3 s, sys: 136 ms, total: 56.5 s
    Wall time: 56.6 s
    sage: %time Y = generate_covers(A)
    CPU times: user 31 s, sys: 65.4 ms, total: 31 s
    Wall time: 31 s
```

I mainly post the algorithm here for documentation, but I would certainly highly appreciate suggestions for improvements.